# Sub-sequence of Vowels

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was practicing for an interview and came across this question on a website:

> A magical sub-sequence of a string `S` is a sub-sequence of `S` that
>   contains all five vowels in order. Find the length of largest magical sub-sequence of a string `S`.
>
> For example, if `S = aeeiooua`, then `aeiou` and `aeeioou` are magical sub-sequences
>   but `aeio` and `aeeioua` are not.

I am a beginner in dynamic programming and am finding it hard to come up with a recursive formula for this.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-3-longest-increasing-subsequence/)?

Comment: In which website u got this question?

Comment: I got the same question in coding test for a company. Could you please tell which website you got this question from?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53998563/longest-ordered-subsequence-of-vowels-dynamic-programming/54047747?noredirect=1#comment94967340_54047747

Answer (score 5):

I did it with an iterative approach rather than recursive one. I started building solution similar to LIS (Longest Increasing Subsequence) and then optimised it upto O(n).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

string vowel = "aeiou";

int vpos(char c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        if (c == vowel[i])
            return i;
    return -1;
}

int magical(string s)
{
    int l = s.length();
    int previndex[5] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1};    // for each vowel
    vector<int> len (l, 0);
    int i = 0, maxlen = 0;

    // finding first 'a'
    while (s[i] != 'a')
    {
        ++i;
        if (i == l)
            return 0;
    }

    previndex[0] = i;       //prev index of 'a'
    len[i] = 1;

    for ( ++i; i < l; ++i)
    {
        if (vpos(s[i]) >= 0)    // a vowel
        {
            /* Need to append to longest subsequence on its left, only for this vowel (for any vowels) and 
             * its previous vowel (if it is not 'a')
                This important observation makes it O(n) -- differnet from typical LIS
            */
            if (previndex[vpos(s[i])] >= 0)
                len[i] = 1+len[previndex[vpos(s[i])]];

            previndex[vpos(s[i])] = i;

            if (s[i] != 'a')
            {
                if (previndex[vpos(s[i])-1] >= 0)
                    len[i] = max(len[i], 1+len[previndex[vpos(s[i])-1]]);
            }

            maxlen = max(maxlen, len[i]);
        }
    }
    return maxlen;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "aaejkioou";
    cout << magical(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O(input string length) runtime
    import java.util.*;

```
public class Main {
    /*
        algo:
        keep map of runningLongestSubsequence that ends in each letter. loop through String s. for each char, try appending
        to runningLongestSubsequence for that char, as well as to runningLongestSubsequence for preceding char.
        update map with whichever results in longer subsequence.

        for String s = "ieaeiouiaooeeeaaeiou", final map is:
        terminal letter in longest running subsequence-> longest running subsequence
        a -> aaaa
        e -> aeeeee
        i -> aeeeeei
        o -> aeeeeeio
        u -> aeeeeeiou

        naming:
        precCharMap - precedingCharMap
        runningLongestSubMap - runningLongestSubsequenceMap
     */

    public static int longestSubsequence(String s) {

        if (s.length() <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        Map<Character, Character> precCharMap = new HashMap<>();
        precCharMap.put('u', 'o');
        precCharMap.put('o', 'i');
        precCharMap.put('i', 'e');
        precCharMap.put('e', 'a');

        Map<Character, String> runningLongestSubMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (char currChar : s.toCharArray()) {
            //get longest subs
            String currCharLongestSub;
            String precCharLongestSub = null;
            if (currChar == 'a') {
                currCharLongestSub = runningLongestSubMap.getOrDefault(currChar, "");
            } else {
                currCharLongestSub = runningLongestSubMap.get(currChar);
                char precChar = precCharMap.get(currChar);
                precCharLongestSub = runningLongestSubMap.get(precChar);
            }

            //update running longest subsequence map
            if (precCharLongestSub == null && currCharLongestSub != null) {
                updateRunningLongestSubMap(currCharLongestSub, currChar, runningLongestSubMap);
            } else if (currCharLongestSub == null && precCharLongestSub != null) {
                updateRunningLongestSubMap(precCharLongestSub, currChar, runningLongestSubMap);
            } else if (currCharLongestSub != null && precCharLongestSub != null) {
                //pick longer
                if (currCharLongestSub.length() < precCharLongestSub.length()) {
                    updateRunningLongestSubMap(precCharLongestSub, currChar, runningLongestSubMap);
                } else {
                    updateRunningLongestSubMap(currCharLongestSub, currChar, runningLongestSubMap);
                }
            }
        }

        if (runningLongestSubMap.get('u') == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return runningLongestSubMap.get('u').length();
    }

    private static void updateRunningLongestSubMap(String longestSub, char currChar,
                                                   Map<Character, String> runningLongestSubMap) {
        String currCharLongestSub = longestSub + currChar;
        runningLongestSubMap.put(currChar, currCharLongestSub);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //String s = "aeeiooua"; //7
        //String s = "aeiaaioooaauuaeiou"; //10
        String s = "ieaeiouiaooeeeaaeiou"; //9
        //String s = "ieaeou"; //0
        //String s = "ieaeoooo"; //0
        //String s = "aeiou"; //5
        //if u have String s beginning in "ao", it'll do nothing with o and 
        //continue on to index 2.

        System.out.println(longestSubsequence(s));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;
unsigned int getcount(string a, unsigned int l,unsigned int r );
int main()
{    
    std::string a("aaaaaeeeeaaaaiiioooeeeeuuuuuuiiiiiaaaaaaoo"
                 "oooeeeeiiioooouuuu");
    //std::string a("aaaaaeeeeaaaaiiioooeeeeuuuuuuiiiiiaaaaaaoooooeeeeiiioooo"); 
   //std::string a("aaaaaeeeeaaaaiiioooeeeeiiiiiaaaaaaoooooeeeeiiioooo"); //sol0
  //std::string a{"aeiou"};
  unsigned int len = a.length();
  unsigned int i=0,cnt =0,countmax =0;
  bool newstring = true;
  while(i<len)
  {
      if(a.at(i) == 'a' && newstring == true) 
      {
          newstring = false;
          cnt = getcount(a,i,len);
          if(cnt > countmax) 
          {
             countmax = cnt;
             cnt = 0;
          }
        } 
        else if(a.at(i)!='a')
        {
            newstring = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    cout<<countmax;
    return 0;
}

unsigned int getcount(string a, unsigned int l,unsigned int r )
{
    std::string b("aeiou");
    unsigned int seq=0,cnt =0;
    unsigned int current =l;
    bool compstr = false;
    while(current<r)
    {
        if(a.at(current) == b.at(seq)) 
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        else if((seq <= (b.size()-2)) && (a.at(current) == b.at(seq+1)))
        {
            seq++; 
            cnt++;
            if (seq == 4) 
                compstr =true;
        }
        current++;
    }
    if (compstr == true) 
        return cnt;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this may not be the best solution , I am looking for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

you can use recursive approach here (this should work for string length upto max int (easily memorization can be used)

```
public class LMV {

static final int NOT_POSSIBLE = -1000000000;
// if out put is this i.e soln not possible 


static int longestSubsequence(String s, char[] c) {

    //exit conditions
    if(s.length() ==0 || c.length ==0){
        return 0;
    }

    if(s.length() < c.length){
        return NOT_POSSIBLE;
    }

    if(s.length() == c.length){
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            if(s.charAt(i) !=c [i]){
                return NOT_POSSIBLE;
            }
        }
        return s.length();
    }

    if(s.charAt(0) < c[0]){
        // ignore, go ahead with next item
        return longestSubsequence(s.substring(1), c);
    } else if (s.charAt(0) == c[0]){
        // <case 1> include item and start search for next item in chars
        // <case 2> include but search for same item again in chars
        // <case 3> don't include item

        return Math.max(
                Math.max(  ( 1+longestSubsequence(s.substring(1), Arrays.copyOfRange(c, 1, c.length) ) ),
                            ( 1+longestSubsequence(s.substring(1), c ) ) ),
                ( longestSubsequence(s.substring(1), c )) );
    } else {
        //ignore
        return longestSubsequence(s.substring(1), c);
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] chars = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

    String s1 = "aeio";
    String s2 = "aaeeieou";
    String s3 = "aaeeeieiioiiouu";

    System.out.println(longestSubsequence(s1, chars));
    System.out.println(longestSubsequence(s2, chars));
    System.out.println(longestSubsequence(s3, chars));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
int func( char *p)
{
    char *temp = p;
    char ae[] = {'a','e','i','o','u'};

    int size = strlen(p), i = 0;
    int chari = 0, count_aeiou=0;
    for (i=0;i<=size; i++){
        if (temp[i] == ae[chari]) {
            count_aeiou++;
        }
        else if ( temp[i] == ae[chari+1]) {
            count_aeiou++;
            chari++;
        }
    }
    if (chari == 4 ) {
        printf ("Final count : %d ", count_aeiou);
    } else {
        count_aeiou = 0;
    }
    return count_aeiou;
}
```

The solution to retrun the VOWELS count as per the hackerrank challenge.

Answer (score 0):

```
int findsubwithcontinuousvowel(string str){
    int curr=0;
    int start=0,len=0,maxlen=0,i=0;
    for(i=0;i<str.size();i++){
        if(str[i]=='u' && (current[curr]=='u' ||  (curr+1<5 && current[curr+1]=='u'))){
           //len++;
           maxlen=max(len+1,maxlen);
        }

        if(str[i]==current[curr]){
            len++;
        }
        else if(curr+1<5 && str[i]==current[curr+1]){
            len++;
            curr++;
        }
        else{
            len=0;
            curr=0;
            if(str[i]=='a'){
                len=1;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxlen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if vowels are available in sequence in `isInSequence` and process the result on `processor`.

```
public class one {

private char[] chars = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
private int a = 0;

private boolean isInSequence(char c){
    // check if char is repeating
    if (c == chars[a]){
        return true;
    }
    // if vowels are in sequence and just passed by 'a' and so on...
    if (c == 'e' && a == 0){
        a++;
        return true;
    }
    if (c == 'i' && a == 1){
        a++;
        return true;
    }
    if (c == 'o' && a == 2){
        a++;
        return true;
    }
    if (c == 'u' && a == 3){
        a++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private char[] processor(char[] arr){
    int length = arr.length-1;
    int start = 0;
    // In case if all chars are vowels, keeping length == arr
    char array[] = new char[length];

    for (char a : arr){
        if (isInSequence(a)){
            array[start] = a;
            start++;
        }
    }
    return array;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    char[] arr = {'m','a','e','l','x','o','i','o','u','a'};
    one o = new one();
    System.out.print(o.processor(arr));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ios ios::sync_with_stdio(NULL);cin.tie(NULL);cout.tie(NULL);
#define ll unsigned long long
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
 ios
string s;
cin>>s;
int n=s.length();
int dp[n+1][5]={0};
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    if(s[i-1]=='a')
    {
        dp[i][0]=1+dp[i-1][0];
        dp[i][1]=dp[i-1][1];
        dp[i][2]=dp[i-1][2];
        dp[i][3]=dp[i-1][3];
        dp[i][4]=dp[i-1][4];
    }
    else if(s[i-1]=='e')
    {dp[i][0]=dp[i-1][0];
    if(dp[i-1][0]>0)
        {dp[i][1]=1+max(dp[i-1][1],dp[i-1][0]);}
        else
        dp[i-1][1]=0;
        dp[i][2]=dp[i-1][2];
        dp[i][3]=dp[i-1][3];
        dp[i][4]=dp[i-1][4];
    }
     else if(s[i-1]=='i')
    {dp[i][0]=dp[i-1][0];
    if(dp[i-1][1]>0)
        {dp[i][2]=1+max(dp[i-1][1],dp[i-1][2]);}
        else
        dp[i-1][2]=0;
        dp[i][1]=dp[i-1][1];
        dp[i][3]=dp[i-1][3];
        dp[i][4]=dp[i-1][4];
    }
    else if(s[i-1]=='o')
    {dp[i][0]=dp[i-1][0];
    if(dp[i-1][2]>0)
        {dp[i][3]=1+max(dp[i-1][3],dp[i-1][2]);}
        else
        dp[i-1][3]=0;
        dp[i][2]=dp[i-1][2];
        dp[i][1]=dp[i-1][1];
        dp[i][4]=dp[i-1][4];
    }
    else if(s[i-1]=='u')
    {dp[i][0]=dp[i-1][0];
       if(dp[i-1][3]>0)
        {dp[i][4]=1+max(dp[i-1][4],dp[i-1][3]);}
        else
        dp[i-1][4]=0;
        dp[i][1]=dp[i-1][1];
        dp[i][3]=dp[i-1][3];
        dp[i][2]=dp[i-1][2];
    }
    else
    {
        dp[i][0]=dp[i-1][0];
        dp[i][1]=dp[i-1][1];
        dp[i][2]=dp[i-1][2];
        dp[i][3]=dp[i-1][3];
        dp[i][4]=dp[i-1][4];
    }


}
cout<<dp[n][4];


return 0;
}
```