# Longest Ordered Subsequence of Vowels - Dynamic Programming

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization, subsequence

Given a string consisting of only vowels, find the longest subsequence in the given string such that it consists of all five vowels and is a sequence of one or more a’s, followed by one or more e’s, followed by one or more i’s, followed by one or more o’s and followed by one or more u’s.

If there is more than one longest subsequence, print any one.

**QUESTION: can u pls show how u would add memoization to soln below/show how to solve using dp?** I've seen how to solve recursively (below). I'm asking for help in arriving at dp soln.

Examples:

Input :  str = "aeiaaioooaauuaeiou" 
Output :  {a, a, a, a, a, a, e, i, o, u}
There are two possible outputs in this case: 
{a, a, a, a, a, a, e, i, o, u} and, 
{a, e, i, i, o, o, o, u, u, u}
each of length 10

Input : str = "aaauuiieeou"
Output : No subsequence possible

Approach:
We loop through all the characters in the string recursively and follow the given conditions:

If the subsequence is empty, we include the vowel at the current index only if it is ‘a’. Otherwise, we move on to the next index.
If the vowel at the current index is same as the last vowel included in the subsequence, we include it.
If the vowel at the current index is the next possible vowel (i.e a–> e–> i–> o–> u ) after the last vowel included in the subsequence, we have two options: either include it or move on to the next index. Hence we choose the one which gives the longest subsequence.
If none of the above conditions is satisfied, we move on to the next index (to avoid invalid ordering of vowels in the subsequence).
If we have reached the end of the string, we check if the current subsequence is valid or not. If it is valid (i.e if it contains all the vowels), we return it, else we return an empty list.

```
# Python3 program to find the longest subsequence 
# of vowels in the specified order 

vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] 

# Mapping values for vowels 
mapping = {'a': 0, 'e': 1, 'i': 2, 'o': 3, 'u': 4} 

# Function to check if given subsequence 
# contains all the vowels or not 
def isValidSequence(subList): 

    for vowel in vowels: 
        if vowel not in subList: 
            return False

    return True

# Function to find the longest subsequence of vowels 
# in the given string in specified order 
def longestSubsequence(string, subList, index): 

    # If we have reached the end of the string, 
    # return the subsequence 
    # if it is valid, else return an empty list 
    if index == len(string): 
        if isValidSequence(subList) == True: 
            return subList 
        else: 
            return [] 

    else: 
        # If there is no vowel in the subsequence yet, 
        # add vowel at current index if it is 'a', 
        # else move on to the next character 
        # in the string 
        if len(subList) == 0: 

            if string[index] != 'a': 
                return longestSubsequence(string, subList, index + 1) 
            else: 
                return longestSubsequence(string, subList + \ 
                            [string[index]], index + 1) 

        # If the last vowel in the subsequence until 
        # now is same as the vowel at current index, 
        # add it to the subsequence 
        elif mapping[subList[-1]] == mapping[string[index]]: 
            return longestSubsequence(string, subList + \ 
                            [string[index]], index + 1) 

        # If the vowel at the current index comes 
        # right after the last vowel 
        # in the subsequence, we have two options: 
        # either to add the vowel in 
        # the subsequence, or move on to next character. 
        # We choose the one which gives the longest subsequence. 
        elif (mapping[subList[-1]] + 1) == mapping[string[index]]: 

            sub1 = longestSubsequence(string, subList + \ 
                                [string[index]], index + 1) 
            sub2 = longestSubsequence(string, subList, index + 1) 

            if len(sub1) > len(sub2): 
                return sub1 
            else: 
                return sub2 

        else: 
            return longestSubsequence(string, subList, index + 1) 

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == "__main__": 

    string = "aeiaaioooauuaeiou"

    subsequence = longestSubsequence(string, [], 0) 
    if len(subsequence) == 0: 
        print("No subsequence possible") 
    else: 
        print(subsequence)
```

Output:
['a', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u']

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47034920/6024572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key realization for memoizing your function is that you can use `(last_chosen_char, length, index)` as your memo key. In other words, treat `"aaeeeiiioo", i=15` and `"aaaaaaaeio", i=15` as identical, because their last chosen characters, lengths and current indices are equivalent. The subproblems of both calls will have identical solutions and we only need to bother computing one of them.

A few additional remarks:

- Avoid global variables which break encapsulation of your functions, which should work as black boxes and not have external dependencies.
- Use default parameters or a helper function to hide unnecessary parameters from the caller and offer a clean interface.
- Since lists aren't hashable (because they're mutable), I switched to using strings.
- After memoization, your call stack is the new bottleneck. You can consider using loops to collect series of duplicates. Similarly, once you've chosen a `"u"`, you might as well loop and collect all remaining `"u"`s in the string; there are no more decisions to be made. You might wish to pre-process the input string a bit to prune off more of the call stack. For example, record the next char position for each index and bail early once you've hit the last `"u"`. None of this would help the worst case, though, so rewriting the logic iteratively using a bottom-up approach would be optimal.

Putting it together, you can now input strings up to the length of the stack size:

```py
def longest_subsequence(string):
    def helper(chosen="", i=0):
        if i == len(string):
            return chosen if set("aeiou").issubset(set(chosen)) else ""

        hashable = (chosen[-1] if chosen else None, len(chosen), i)

        if hashable in memo:
            return memo[hashable]

        if not chosen:
            res = helper("a" if string[i] == "a" else chosen, i + 1)
        elif chosen[-1] == string[i]:
            res = helper(chosen + string[i], i + 1)
        elif mapping[chosen[-1]] + 1 == mapping[string[i]]:
            sub1 = helper(chosen + string[i], i + 1)
            sub2 = helper(chosen, i + 1)

            res = sub1 if len(sub1) > len(sub2) else sub2
        else:
            res = helper(chosen, i + 1)

        memo[hashable] = res
        return res

    mapping = {x: i for i, x in enumerate("aeiou")}
    memo = {}
    return helper()
```

Here's an example run on a string of 900 characters:

```
original: uouoouiuoueaeeiiiaaaouuuueuaiaeaioaaiouaouiaiiaiuuueaueaieeueeuuouioaoaeueoioeoeioiuiaiaoeuuuuauuaiuueiieaauuoieiuoiaiueeeoaeaueaaaiaiiieuaoaiaaoiaoaueouaiiooaeeoioiaoieouuuoeaoaeeaaiuieouaeeooiiuooeauueaoaoaeuoaieauooueeeuiueuaeoeouuuiaoiauiaoiaaeeoeouuuueuiiuueoeeoiieuuuauooeuuaaaueuaaaaoaieaiiuoaoouueeeooiuoieoaueooaaioaeoiiiauuoeiaioeauaueiiaeoueioeiieuoiueoeoueeiuiooaioeooueuioaoaeoaiiiauoooieueoeauaiauauuauoueeauouieeoeoeiaeeeeooooeoaueouuuuiioeeuioueeuiaiueooeueeuuuoooeeuooeuoeeeaiioeeiioauiaeaiuaiauooiioeoeueoeieuueouaeeuuoeuaueeeauiiaoeeaeuieoeiuoooeaeeiuaiauuieouuuiuouiuieieoueiiaoiuioaiououooieiauuuououuiiiuaoeeieueeiuoeiaouoeueieuoiaeuoeiieeeaaaeiaeeoauoaoeuuoiiaaeiuiouueaoeuueeoouiaeeeouiouaaaeiouaaeauauioeoeuiauaeaououoaiuuueuieiaeeaouuueeaaiauoieoioaoiuuaioaiauioueieuuuueiaeeuaoeeoeioeoaiauiiuaouuoouooouaeueaioiaouuiiuauiaaeooeueiuoiuoeeauueuuueuueouiiauiuaoiuuoeuoeeauaeoo    
max subsequence: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiiiiiooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/AcclaimedFuchsiaPerformance)

Comment: "(last_chosen_char, length, index) as your memo key." even if they r not of same length, The subsequent calls of both will have identical solutions if just last_chosen_char and index same ya? given "aeeeiiioo", i=*14* and "aaaaaaaeio", i=15, we can memoize the subsequent calls after "o" using just (last_chosen_char, index), append to both prefixes, and see which is longer ya? or we can even only compute for the prefix that currently has longer length and ignore the prefix of shorter length ya?

Comment: thank u ggorlen! "After memoization, your call stack is the new bottleneck." Right, for example if I see the same string @ a greater index, I know result from lesser index will be greater or equal to result from greater index, yes? E.g. if i call helper("aee", 7) and helper("aee", 9), result of helper("aee", 7) >= result of helper("aee", 9).

Comment: It's tempting to want to make the memo keys broader so you get more cache hits--I tried that myself in the course of writing this answer. But if you create a false equivalence between two states that are actually distinct, you compromise correctness, which omitting the length does. Try it out and see. As for your second remark, I don't quite follow, but what I mean by recursion as bottleneck is that each char basically has to have its own function call. If the stack size is 1000, the biggest string you can process is 999 or so (including `main`). So the next step is writing this iteratively.

Comment: i drew out call tree for eaeeieeoauiou and with memo key as last_chosen_char, length, index, i don't think it hits memo table even once; would this memo key only be useful with very large examples (or maybe not even that, maybe just very specific subset of examples)?

Comment: non-memoized soln above has upperbound runtime of 2^(input string length) yes?

Comment: do u mean iteratively as ive written in comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554450/sub-sequence-of-vowels/53992057#53992057? i couldn't think of a way to use tabulation. i tried col headers as string lengths from 0 to len(string), with row headers as each individual character in string. i tried col headers as each individual character in string and row headers as the 5 magic vowels. if u can think of way to use tabulation, please share!

Comment: Upper bound, yes O(2^n), because worst case you hit the double branch on every char and create 2 recursive calls. For Java, I would multiply the ASCII value of the `last_chosen_char` by some prime number and do similar for the `length` and `index` and sum them. It's not surprising you're not getting hits on a short string like that and it's not going to save much work anyway. There may be a way to improve the key efficiency to generate more hits, but the important thing is correctness. I haven't thought a lot about a bottom-up iterative DP on this one, but if I have time I'll try to code it.

Comment: [Also useful for hashing in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash(java.lang.Object...))

Comment: thank u so much ggorlen; u r helping me tremendously. in java, how would u use (last_chosen_char, length, index) as your memo key? a 3D array? would you create a hashcode from those 3 vars as u've done above and stick with a 1d array/map? u could also make a set of the 3 vars and use a map, but no reason to choose that over hashcode -> map

Comment: oops wanted to edit my cmnt and didnt realize u had already responded, so now theyre out of order ^^. pls note that i did come up with iterative O(n) soln in cmnts here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554450/sub-sequence-of-vowels/53992057#53992057 I just didnt do it using tabulation. not sure how to or if possible

Comment: Nice job. Looks like the top-voted answer on that page shows how to do it with a table.

Comment: thank you! just checked it out. so with her example of string s = "aaejkioou", @G_S would start her for loop 'for ( ++i; i < l; ++i)' @ index i=1, the 2nd 'a', yes? confirming because i think there's typo in 'for ( ++i; i < l; ++i)'.

Comment: her soln seems similar to my iterative soln: "attempt to append current vowel to longest subsequence for current vowel and previous vowel (latter only if current vowel is not 'a')". however her soln got a little confusing for me as i stepped through keeping track of variables. i may have 2 try again. also even if her soln is correct, i believe she'd have to return the longest subsequence ending in u (i think this would be len[previndex[vpos(s[4])]]) and not maxlen?

Comment: looking @ her soln did allow me to quickly realize my iterative soln is doing overkill in terms of info. tracked. rather than keeping running longest subsequence for each vowel, i can change my runningLongestSubMap to be vowel -> length of longest running subsequence ending in that vowel. this soln, which i may implement and which is nearly identical to my current iterative soln, is very simple. we wouldn't really need to do whatever G_S is doing with an additional 'len' vector or to track prevIndex for subsequence ending in each vowel as she's doing. agreed? :)

Comment: also like her intuitive approach of looping and doing nothing until 1st a found.

Comment: using tabulation framework i've come to: col headers as each vowel (aeiou). row headers as each char in string (e.g. aaejkioou). say currChar is 'o'. then we'd say table[currRow][3] = 1+max(table[currRow-1][2], table[currRow-1][3]), with couple of logic checks of course. altho it would only save you a constant amount of time, bc u only need most recent values, you could also just use a '1 x vowel' size table. this eliminates work of carrying down values that arent changing.

Comment: result is pretty much same as using map. so i was using tabulation approach the entire time. iterative map essentially equivalent to iterative tabulation. which has me thinking, could u do this for most tabulation problems such as longest common subseq., knapsack, or power set? will have 2 try but i dont see why not bc u only need most recent values.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static int longestSubSeqOfVowels(String input) {

    char[] v = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    HashMap<Character, Integer> charCount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    char c;
    int vCount = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        c = input.charAt(i);
        if (vCount == -1 && c != 'a') {
            continue;

        }
        int value = charCount.get(c) == null ? 0 : charCount.get(c) + 1;
        if (value == 0) {

            if (c == v[vCount + 1]) {
                value = vCount >= 0 ? charCount.get(v[vCount]) + 1 : 1;
                vCount++;
            }

            charCount.put(c, value);

        } else {
            charCount.put(c, value);
        }
    }
    return charCount.get('u').intValue();
}
```

The above is to get the length of the longest subsequence of vowels.. The same can be modified to get the String as we are keeping the count of each char in a map.